# Apache Rampart Axis2 Symmetric policy

Tags: apache-axis, rampart

How to generate client for WSDL which has Symmetric Binding policy using axis2 and Apache Rampart?I am able to generate client using axis2 and eclipse, after that how can i add Apache Rampart configuration(Symmetric binding) for generated Client? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with [this](http://wso2.org/library/3190) tutorial. After that, I recommend looking at the Rampart samples provided in the bundle, a symmetric scenario is included there, runnable example.